# How set google visualization chart from zero

Tags: javascript, html

I have example from Google visualization, which draw chart on HTML page:

- column2 equals 120
- column3 equals 125

But in this example value start from 118.

How change code, that value start from 0 (X-axis) ?

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
     <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <title>Report</title>
      <style>
       #Header {
       height:40px;
       font-size:24px;
       padding-left:5px;
       padding-top:5px;
       color:#FFFFFF;
        background: ff0022; /* For old browser */
        background-image: -webkit-gradient(
            linear,
            left top,
            right top,
            color-stop(0, #FF0022),
            color-stop(0.80, #FFFCFD)
        );
        background-image: -o-linear-gradient(right, #FF0022 0%, #FFFCFD 80%);
        background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(right, #FF0022 0%, #FFFCFD 80%);
        background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(right, #FF0022 0%, #FFFCFD 80%);
        background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(right, #FF0022 0%, #FFFCFD 80%);
        background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #FF0022 0%, #FFFCFD 80%);
       }
       #BodyEmail
       {
            font-size:17px;
            margin-left:10px;
       }
       .successful
       {
        color:#339900;
       }
       .failed
       {
        color:#CC0000;
       }
       #chart
       {
          width:80%;
          margin-left:30px;
          margin-top:10px;    
       }
      </style>
      <script src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
      <script>
    google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});

         google.setOnLoadCallback(tfsTimeBuildDefinition);
           function tfsTimeBuildDefinition() {
            var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
             ['Column1', 'Column2','Column3'],
             ['', 120,125]
            ]);
            var options = {
             title: 'Total time',
             hAxis: {title: 'Test'},
             vAxis: {title: 'Spent time (sec)'}
            };
            var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('testChart'));
            chart.draw(data, options);
           }

      </script>
     </head>
     <body>
        <div id="testChart" style="width: 700px; height: 400px;"></div>
     </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this solution, I hope it would help you,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
     <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <title>RRD.ActiveLink report</title>
      <style>
       #Header {
       height:40px;
       font-size:24px;
       padding-left:5px;
       padding-top:5px;
       color:#FFFFFF;
        background: ff0022; /* For old browser */
        background-image: -webkit-gradient(
            linear,
            left top,
            right top,
            color-stop(0, #FF0022),
            color-stop(0.80, #FFFCFD)
        );
        background-image: -o-linear-gradient(right, #FF0022 0%, #FFFCFD 80%);
        background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(right, #FF0022 0%, #FFFCFD 80%);
        background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(right, #FF0022 0%, #FFFCFD 80%);
        background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(right, #FF0022 0%, #FFFCFD 80%);
        background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #FF0022 0%, #FFFCFD 80%);
       }
       #BodyEmail
       {
            font-size:17px;
            margin-left:10px;
       }
       .successful
       {
        color:#339900;
       }
       .failed
       {
        color:#CC0000;
       }
       #chart
       {
          width:80%;
          margin-left:30px;
          margin-top:10px;    
       }
      </style>
      <script src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
      <script>
    google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});

         google.setOnLoadCallback(tfsTimeBuildDefinition);
           function tfsTimeBuildDefinition() {
            var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
             ['Column1', 'Column2','Column3'],
             ['', 10,125]
            ]);
            var options = {
             title: 'Total time',
             hAxis: {title: 'Test'},
             vAxis: {title: 'Spent time (sec)'}
            };
            var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('testChart'));
            chart.draw(data, options);
           }

      </script>
     </head>
     <body>
        <div id="testChart" style="width: 700px; height: 400px;"></div>
     </body>
    </html>
```

Just changed a little.

Comment: No. This is not good idea. I have 2 columns with value more than 100. And I can't set value one of them near 0.

Comment: This can't be manually reset by developer who using it, this only used as automatically rendered using comparing the user given data, and depend on that it choose what it will show in both of it's axis's.